# Inverting without actual inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Ash's *"Basic Abstract Algebra"* and been trying to understand the following:

> [image]

For which I guess the problem lies when we try to take an element $hk\in HK$, it's inverse is $k^{-1}h^{-1}$ but $k^{-1}h^{-1}\in HK$ only if $k^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1} k^{-1}$.

My problem is the following, taking the definition of subgroup, we have:

- If $a,b\in H$, then $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Then, all the elements $k\cdot1=k$ and $1\cdot h=h$ are in $HK$, that is: We have all the elements of both $H,K$ in $HK$. By the definition, suppose we have $hk\in HK$, then we must have $(hk)(k^{-1})$ and $(hkk^{-1})(h^{-1})$. Isn't this very similar to having the inverse of $hk$ in $HK$?

It's a bit odd because it seems we can actually invert $hk$ by performing the two operations I mentioned before but $(hk)^{-1}$ is not actually in $HK$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. I guess you want to prove that $HK \le G$ implies $HK = KH$. The converse is fairly obvious.

Comment: I think your confusion stems from the way you're looking at this. Notice that $(hk)(k^{-1})$ must be in $HK$ trivially since it's $h$ same for $(hk)(k^{-1})(h^{-1})$ since that is just $1$. But just because $ab\in HK$ that says nothing about $a$ or $b$ being in $HK$ unless you know $HK$ is a group. Even if you know $a\in HK$ and $ab\in HK$ you only get $b$ in $HK$ **if** $HK$ is a group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$Allow me first of all to question your statement

> when we try to take an element $hk\in HK$, its inverse is $k^{-1}h^{-1}$ but $k^{-1}h^{-1}\in HK$ only if $k^{-1}h^{-1}=h^{-1} k^{-1}$.

This is not true. Take for instance $G = S_{3}$, $H = \Span{(1 2)}$, $K = \Span{(1 2 3)}$, $h = (1 2)$, $k = (1 2 3)$. Then $h^{-1} k^{-1} = (2 3) \ne (1 3) = k^{-1} h^{-1} \in H K = S_{3}$.

As to your second statement

> suppose we have $hk\in HK$, then we must have $(hk)(k^{-1})$ and $(hkk^{-1})(h^{-1})$. Isn't this very similar to having the inverse of $hk$ in $HK$?

I fail to see the point. Sure, *$h k$ has an inverse $k^{-1} h^{-1}$ in $G$*, and that's what you are checking. But to show that $H K$ is a subgroup you will have to show that (under suitable conditions) this inverse lies precisely in $H K$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $HK = KH$. To show that $HK$ is a subgroup, consider $g_1= h_1k_1, g_2 = h_2k_2$ in $HK$. We have $(k_1k_2^{-1})h_2^{-1} \in KH = HK$, hence $(k_1k_2^{-1})h_2^{-1} = hk$ with $h \in H, k \in K$. Then $g_1g_2^{-1} = h_1k_1k_2^{-1}h_2^{-1} = h_1hk \in HK$.

If you consider $hk \in HK$, then you see even easier $(hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1} \in KH = HK$.

Conversely, assume that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

(a) $KH \subset HK$.

Let $g \in KH$. Write $g = kh$ with $h \in H, k \in K$. Then $g^{-1} = h^{-1}k^{-1} \in HK$, hence $g \in HK$.

(b) $HK \subset KH$.

Let $g \in HK$. Then also $g^{-1} \in HK$, hence $g^{-1} = hk$ with $h \in H, k \in K$. This shows $g = k^{-1}h^{-1} \in KH$.